# Problem with mutation and asynchronous behavior in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In [react documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/prerequisite-concepts#note-on-immutability-side-effects-and-mutation), it is written that:

> For React-Redux, connect checks to see if the props returned from a
> mapStateToProps function have changed in order to determine if a
> component needs to update. To improve performance, connect takes some
> shortcuts that rely on the state being immutable, and uses shallow
> reference equality checks to detect changes. This means that changes
> made to objects and arrays by direct mutation will not be detected,
> and components will not re-render.

I think direct mutation is something like:

```
this.state.someState = 2
```

What does direct mutation mean here in the case of redux?

The second question that I have and not finding a satisfying answer to it is what can be the side effect of mutation or asynchronous behavior that is mentioned in the below documentation:

> Side effects like mutation or asynchronous behavior will cause time
> travel to alter behavior between steps, breaking the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does direct mutation mean here in the case of redux?

It means directly modifying the values in the Redux store:

```
reduxState.someProperty = 2;
```

or directly modifying anything contained within the Redux store.

To put it simply, you need to update the store by dispatching actions and using pure, synchronous reducer functions.

> The second question that I have and not finding a satisfying answer to it is what can be the side effect of mutation or asynchronous behavior that is mentioned in the below documentation:

Mutation and asynchronous behavior *are* side effects, as it says in the text you quoted. It also states right in that text what the ill effects of this are: time travel (winding the state backwards and forwards) will not work correctly, and attempting to wind back to a previous state will actually give you something whose values are not consistent with what were actually in that previous state.

Answer (score 1):

> What does direct mutation mean here in the case of redux?

It means if your reducer mutates the state and returns it:

```js
function myReducer(state, action) {
   this.state.someState = 2
   return state
}
```

then Redux won't think a change occurred because the returned value references the previous state. The reducer needs to return a new value.

> what can be the side effect of mutation or asynchronous behavior

A side effect mutation looks like:

```js
function myReducer(state, action) {
   this.state.someState = 2
   return { someState: this.state.someState + 1 }
}
```

Even though a new value was returned, the previous state was mutated in place. As a result, if you [time-travel-debug](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools) to the previous state, you will not see its actual value, but instead `2`.

An example of an async side effect is:

```js
function myReducer(state, action) {
   return new Promise(res => {
     return state + 2;
   })
}
```

Any async behavior in your reducer will cause it to return a promise, which will show up in state and likely be invalid data for your components.

Comment: Thanks @bsapaka, what is the meaning of 'time-travel-debug' here?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker it means being able to step forward/backward through any previous state-changes. You can see any representation of your state at any given point in time. Check out Redux-devtools: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools